# Javascript doesn't load in Django template

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, django-templates

I want to add some javascript function in python django template but the staticfile I load doesn't load the javasctipt file . The file doesn't have ?v=2.17 but I want them to for jquery version

```
<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

Rendered Code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
        });
    </script>
```

This is my settings.py file and url.py file from project :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/var/www/static/',
]
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'
```

**Expected OutCome:**

[image]

**Real Outcome:**

[image]

**debugger**

[image]

Comment: Paste the rendered HTML you are getting.

Comment: @GrandPhuba I have now ..

Comment: I mean the HTML. In the browser, press "CTRL+U" (e.g. view source)

Comment: @GrandPhuba Is it ok now??

Comment: Yes. From the rendered code the file does have the `v=2.1.7`. The issue must be unrelated to the version. Open the debugger (CTRL+SHIFT+J), and show the error as well

Comment: I have done it .can you have a look

Comment: You mind posting the entirety of the rendered HTML and your template code, not just just script sections. The error seems to be outside what you have shown so far